# Is it possible to combine Doxygen commands?

Tags: doxygen

`\todo \image html clone.png`

The intent here is to place an image inside the `todo` but it appears that when you put one tag after another, the tag is ignored. Is there a way to do this? I've tried it with more than just `\image`, it appears to be the case with any two tags you use in succession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to get images into your documentation.  Maybe try with html and it might not break your \todo command.

```
\todo <IMG SRC=clone.png>
```

You can also create an alias in your setup file that makes it easy and clean to include your image.

I too have found that some commands seem to end other commands.  Note that not ALL commands will end your "\todo" command.  Font commands such as \c like in the example for \arg does not end the command.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdarg

Comment: do you mean an alias that would include this HTML above?

Comment: Incidentally this doesn't resolve the issue of using a Doxygen tag that doesn't have an obvious HTML equivalent, such as `\todo \code`

Comment: Yes, an alias that take your custom alias such as \myimage{clone.png} and convert it to the HTML.  But this is also getting off topic.

The short answer for this is NO, there are some commands you just can't combine.  (note they are called commands.  Tag files are something quite different in Doxygen vocabulary).